# How to make low-calorie bread?

Tags: bread

I live in a part of the world, where you can't buy low calorie bread in the stores. So I'm obsessed with the idea to make my own.

I've noticed that breads as this one https://www.schmidtoldtyme.com/647-bread/ purportedly have less than a 100 calories per 100 grams and their label says they are basically made with wheat flour. But how can you turn wheat four that has energy content well above 350 calories per 100 grams into bread that has less than 100 calories in the same amount of bread?

I thought that the basic idea is to add other flours besides wheat. But if the energy content labels on my local products are correct, then almost any flour (barley, rice, rye, etc.) has energy content that equivalent to wheat. Except the ones that are made from nuts - they have almost twice the energy content.

Is it some clever way to add and hold water ? What is the secret ? Is it only a marketing fad of some kind ?

Can you help?

Comment: I've read the label again. What does "modified variety" means as description of weat. Does it mean that the wheat is genetically altered to have less energy content ?

Comment: You seem to be misreading the label. The bread you linked has 40 calories per serving of 27 grams, which is about 130 calories per 100 grams. This is still less than typical bread, but not as radical as your question presents it. Also, the calories in bread are not the same as the calories as wheat.

Comment: Yes, the bread sure holds some water in it after is backed (I must carefuly weigh the ready product from one of my baking experiments to get an idea how much). But how they managed to get it to 130 calories from say 260 for typical bread?

Comment: I suspect that they might be using insoluble fiber (fiber that your body can’t absorb) to bulk it up.  They used to use cellulose in the US for ‘diet bran muffins’, but people didn’t like the idea of eating sawdust.  (Which had been used in occupied areas in WW2 as well, so people had something to fill their bellies during food shortages)

Comment: It's pretty simple really, they all have about 8 grams of fiber per slice which is really really high, you are usually getting 1 or 2 in most breads. So literally 30 percent of the slice is going straight through you.